# Problems runing a code with ipynb in google drive

Tags: python, drive

Sooo, this is more of theoretical question. I have a python code that runs just fine in Pycharm but started to not work anymore in my .ipynb drive file. It downloads and writes over a binary document.
The code fails were trying to open the downloaded file for writing with the error message that '[Errno 2] No such file or directory:'.
I'm not sure if it is involved in the problem, but these lines below used to run without warnings, but now google drive asks for my permission for them to run:

`drive.mount('/content/drive')                                                                            drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)`

As a told before, since the code runs without error in pycharm, I was wondering if you guys know whether this is a "google drive new update" kinda of thing, or a "jupiter notebook problem" or something else maybe?

[EDIT: here's the message google drive sends me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sVyI.png)

Comment: Insert: from google.colab import drive

Comment: Already have, but thanks.

Comment: Unless it's a more complicated issue, could it be that your working directory is still set to whatever it was with pycharm (which doesn't exist on your Google Drive)? If that isn't it, you could try inserting: "from google.colab import files" after mounting the drive. Also, if you aren't switching directories after mounting then at the very least include: %cd "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks" after mounting your drive as I'm not sure '/content/drive' is an accessible folder.